# Python: How to convert string into datetime

Tags: python, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

I am parsing an XML file that gives me the time in the respective isoformat:

```
tc1 = 2012-09-28T16:41:12.9976565
tc2 = 2012-09-28T23:57:44.6636597
```

But it is being treated as a string when I retrieve this from the XML file. 
I have two such time values and i need to do a diff between the two so as to find delta. 
But since it is a string I can not directly do tc2-tc1. But since they are already in isoformat for datetime, how do i get python  to recognize it as datetime?

thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at `datetime.strptime()`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the [`datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) method:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime(your_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

The link provided presents the different format directives. Note that the microseconds are limited to the range `[0,999999]`, meaning that a `ValueError` will be raised with your example (you're using 1/10us): you need to truncate your string to drop the final character.

Comment: quick add on question. once i have the values in datetime, how do i get the time difference?

Comment: `datetime_object_2`-`datetime_object_1` will give you a [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [python-dateutil `parse()` function](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2), it's more flexible than strptime. Hope this help you.

Comment: http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`datetime` module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html).

```
td = datetime.strptime('2012-09-28T16:41:12.997656', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f') - 
     datetime.strptime('2012-09-28T23:57:44.663659', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
print td
# => datetime.timedelta(-1, 60208, 333997)
```

There is only one small problem: Your microseconds are one digit to long for `%f` to handle. So I've removed the last digits from your input strings.